# Using same spec across different deployment in argocd

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am currently using Kustomize. We are have multiple deployments and services. These have the same `spec` but different names. Is it possible to store the `spec` in individual files & refer them across all the deployments files?

Comment: can't you use helm for templating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm is a good fit for the solution.
However, since we were already using Kustomize & migration to Helm would have needed time, we solved the problem using namePrefix & label modifiers in Kustomize.

Answer (score 0):

Use Helm, in ArgoCD create a pipeline with helm:3 container and create a helm-chart directory or repository. Pull the chart repository, deploy with helm. Use values.yaml for the dynamic values you want to use. Also, you will need to add kubeconfig file to your pipeline but that is another issue.

This is the best offer I can give. For further information I need to inspect ArgoCD.

Comment: Do we need to create a repo or can we do it using the existing github repo

Comment: If you have an existing repository with a helm chart and predefined values of dev-test-prod then you can use it with env variables to deploy to specific cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem and I resolved it using Helm3 charts:

- I have a chart. Yaml file where I indicated my release name and version
- values. Yam where I define all variable to use for a specific environment.
- Values-test. Yaml a file to use, for example, in a test environment where you should only put the variable that must be changed from an environment to another.

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Did you make the changes to your existing repo or did you have to create a new one

Comment: I create a new  repo on each environement for example dev-app1 for dev and test-app1 for test environement .

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using Helm. However a restriction of Helm is that you cannot create dynamic `values.yaml` files (https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6699) - this can be very annoying, especially for multi-environment setups.  However, ArgoCD provides a very nice way to do this with its `Application` type.

The solution is to create a custom Helm chart for generating your ArgoCD applications (which can be called with different config for each environment). The templates in this helm chart will generate ArgoCD `Application` types.  This type supports a `source.helm.values` field where you can dynamically set the `values.yaml`.

For example, the `values.yaml` for [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/helm/configuration) can be highly complex and this is a scenario where a dynamic `values.yaml` per environment is highly desirable (as this prevents having multiple `values.yaml` files for each environment which are large but very similar).

If your custom ArgoCD helm chart is `my-argocd-application-helm`, then the following are example `values.yaml` and the template which generates your Vault application i.e.

#### values.yaml

```yaml
server: 1.2.3.4           # Target kubernetes server for all applications

vault:
  name: vault-dev
  repoURL: https://git.acme.com/myapp/vault-helm.git
  targetRevision: master
  path: helm/vault-chart
  namespace: vault
  hostname: 5.6.7.8       # target server for Vault
  ...
```

#### templates/vault-application.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.vault.name }}
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: 'vault'
    server: {{ .Values.server }}
  project: 'default'
  source:
    path: '{{ .Values.vault.path }}'
    repoURL: {{ .Values.vault.repoURL }}
    targetRevision: {{ .Values.vault.targetRevision }}
    helm:
      # Dynamically generate `values.yaml` 
      values: |
        vault:
          server:
            ingress:
              activeService: true
              hosts:
                - host: {{ required "Please set 'vault.hostname'" .Values.vault.hostname | quote }}
                  paths:
                    - /
            ha:
              enabled: true
              config: |
                ui = true

                ...
```

These values will then override any base configuration residing in the `values.yaml` specified by `{{ .Values.vault.repoURL }}` which can contain config which doesn't change for each environment.